# Lightning App Builder

Tags: discussion

I watched a live webinar callled [Build Apps Visually with Lightning App Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/events/webinars/Lightning-App-Builder?eid=batch) on Wed. For those who missed it, you can get a new Dev Org which has the App Builder enabled at this link: http://bit.ly/lightning-org. Reportedly, the only other way to get it enabled is through your AE. Enjoy!

Comment: I think all new dev orgs have it enabled by default now, it's gone to public beta. (was part of the ligtning week)

Comment: Not according to the webinar on Wed. Was still in beta and not GA.

Comment: So no chance to activate it on the existing dev org yet?

Comment: We were told in the webinar that you'd need to talk with your AE and to justify having it activated in an existing Dev Org. Only way to get it at this point in time is to set up a new Dev Org. Here's the link to the webinar where the video and slides are up: https://developer.salesforce.com/events/webinars/Lightning-App-Builder?eid=batch.

Comment: As an FYI, this past Thursday's Lightning Component Webinar repeated the same info that the only way to get the App Builder enabled in a Dev Org is via a new Dev Org obtained from the above link.

Comment: Interesting. I've got an old dev org and with the Summer '15 release I could see the App Builder available. I also built a proof of concept app for one of our clients... Maybe they got it wrong at the webinar (that needs to be enabled through an AE)?

Comment: @Bachovski with Summer 15, it's now available in all new DE Orgs. Existing orgs that I have were also upgraded to enable it. However, at the time of the Webinar (March), the only way to gain access to the features was via a new DE Org using the link above. The regular link for a new DE Org didn't include the App Builder.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the date of this post, pardon me :)